# how to transform rows into columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe.
It basically says the following:

```
i have 1 cold coffee,0 hot coffee,1 hot sandwich and 1 chips-lays on 20-06-2020
```

```
Order     Type        20-06-2020     21-06-2020

coffee    cold         1              1
          hot          0              1
Sandwich  hot          2              1
chips     Lays         1              2
```

I want new dataframe to be like the following

```
             Coffee-cold     coffee-hot      sandwich-hot   Chips-Lays
20-06-2020    1               0                2              1
21-06-2020    1               1                1              2
```

How can I achieve it?
I have written below code,but it's not working

```
df.pivot(index=["20-06-2020","21-06-2020"],columns="Order"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df=df.T

df.columns=df.columns.map('-'.join)
```